# Serialize file type jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to serialize my form data including file image field using **jquery.form.js** jQuery API.
The API is helping me to serailze data fields including image and return image object as `[object file]`

Here is my code for serialization

```
    var data = $js("form[name=ajx_imgupload]").formSerialize();
    var img = $js("#upload_image").fieldSerialize();

    $js.ajax({
                 url: "index.php?option=com_obituary&task=upload",
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType:"json",
                 data: data,
                 beforeSend: function(){
                   $js(".loadingblock").show();
                 },
                 complete: function(){
                   $js(".loadingblock").hide();
                 },
                 success: function(res){
                   alert();  
                 },
                 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                   alert(textStatus);                
                 }
           });
```

Stuck with issue... Help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

let me help you. I made this just 1 day ago. I have form including image field. when you submit it its uploading image via `jquery.form.js`

Note: I am uploading file with jqueryimageupload.php, if you want I can paste it. It is a simple php file upload. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

html part:

```
<form name="imageform" id="imageform" action="jqueryimageupload.php" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="resim" id="img" onchange="ImageUpload()" />
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="imageup" />
</form>
```

jquery:

```
function ImageUpload() {
    $("#return").show();
    $("#return").html('');
    $("#return").html('<img src="images/load2.gif" alt="Uploading...."/> wait, uploading...');
    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
        target: '#return',
        success: function() {
            $("#return").fadeOut(10000);
        }
   }).submit();     
}
```

at last form submit:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    var img=$('#image').val();
    var forms=($(this).serialize());
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",            
        url: "do.php?do=upload",
        data:forms+'&r='+encodeURIComponent(img),
        success: function(result){ //your code }     
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use this way (from http://portfolio.planetjon.ca/2014/01/26/submit-file-input-via-ajax-jquery-easy-way/)

```
$( '#my-form' )
  .submit( function( e ) {
    $.ajax( {
      url: 'http://host.com/action/',
      type: 'POST',
      data: new FormData( this ),
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    } );
  } );
```

it's more flexible and easy way

Comment: I would add 
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

To avoid submit.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<!--Add Inventory Form-->

<div id="addInventoryFormHTML" class style="display:none">

    <!--Form-->
    <form id="addInventoryForm" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input id="itemTitleField" class="textField addInventoryField" name="itemTitleField" type="text" placeholder="Item Title"/>

        <textarea id="itemDescriptionField" class="textAreaField addInventoryField" name="itemDescriptionField" type="textarea" placeholder="Item Description"></textarea>

        <input id="itemPictureField" class="uploadField addInventoryField" name="itemPictureField" type="file"/>

    </form>

    <!--Errors-->
    <div id="inventoryAddErrors"></div>

</div>
```

Javascript (note that any methods following self are instance methods, I use Joose)

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit({//note that form is just the form built with a jQuery selector

            url: self.returnBaseULR() + '/ajaxadd',

            type: 'POST',

            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Unable to contact the server');
            },

            success: function(response){

                var jsObjectFromResponse = JSON.parse(response);

                if(jsObjectFromResponse.success){

                    self.cLog('Item uploaded successfully!');
                    document.location.reload();

                } else {

                    self.cLog('Listing failed, see AJAX response');

                }

            }

        });
```

You can't upload images using just jQuery native methods. Check out http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

It has methods that'd do this for you perfectly.

That just appears to work for me. On the back end I can grab POST params with $_POST and files with $_FILES (or something like that)

Looks like ajaxSubmit instantly posts the form with serialized data done automatically.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you need any sample code (the html, Javascript and PHP), I have done it with this library, i'll add it to my answer

Comment: I am using this jquery.form.js forum plugin and using formserialize..instead of ajaxform...none of function working with it...stucked and tired

Comment: oh sorry my bad, i didn't read your question properly. I'll add my code see if it helps

Comment: Thanks Adam..hope your code sets with the code i m looking for..thanks

Comment: basically just use ajaxSubmit and forget the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ajax for file upload. To simulate the effect though, you can have a form in a hidden iframe and submit/ `.submit()` it to the upload url.

More or less like [this one.](http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html)

Comment: Any link how to create iframe and clone data will be much appricated..thanks

Comment: @ManeeshMehta: There are so many but I posted one that seemed simple to understand at first glance. For me, I ended up writing a simple one myself. I suggest searching for *"ajax file upload"* and *"file upload using iframe method"*.