# Jquery load() + post form (with imagefield)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using the load() method to POST forms and load the response at the same time. Like this:

```
$("#contentdiv").load('upload/', $('#uploadform').serializeArray());
```

The response could be instances from the database rendered in some child-html page. It can be the same form with errors. Thats why is really want to keep using load(). It makes it smooth to handle built in form errors, CSRF-token etc..

The problem is to POST when one field is an file/imagefield. It doesn't work.

Is it possible to load() + POST form when the form has a filefield? Maybe combined with "ajaxSubmit"?

Thank you all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize file type jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262816/serialize-file-type-jquery)

Comment: have you tried this , `$.post('upload/',$('#uploadform').serialize(),function(response){$("#contentdiv").html(response);});`

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers, Nah.. The submit-works but im getting the form back with error "No file selected".

Comment: jQuery dose not submit files you need to submit your form using hidden iframe ill post answer for that wait

Comment: I've write full code for you check my answer

Comment: Nice! Yes i know that it doesnt submit files thats why i was thinking of combining with ajaxSubmit plugin somehow but maybe the iframe method work as well. I'll try that. It will take a little while because im still a beginner. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to know that jQuery dose not submit `input=file` you need to submit the form using hidden iframe , this is example for that

add this `attribute` to your form `target="uploadframe"`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    //append hidden iframe
    $('body').append('<iframe id="uploadframe" name="uploadframe" style="display:none" />');
    //on form submit
    $('#bb-upload-form').submit(function(){
        //add form action url
        $(this).attr('action', 'upload/');
        //add form target
        $(this).attr('target', 'uploadframe');
        //load response from server submited file
        iframe = $('#uploadframe').load(function () {

            //get response 
            response = iframe.contents().find('body');

            alert(response);

        });
    });
});
</script>
```